# splice inside Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(index)

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it ok to do something like this in node.js:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(index) { 
   if (index == 'sth')
      obj.splice(obj.indexOf(index), 1);
}
```

I wonder if this splice will do the expected thing if the script is executed by many clients writing in/out into the obj object.

Comment: splice doesnt work on objects.

Comment: @JordanHendrix: I think `obj` is an array. Except of course, then `index` would be a number (well, numeric string), not `'sth'`. So...yeah, really quite unclear. :-)

Comment: That code really doesn't make much sense. If `obj` is an array, the `index` will be each of its existing entry indexes and `obj.indexOf(index)` wouldn't make sense as that finds entries, not indexes. If `obj` *isn't* an array, then it won't have `splice` (well, unless you create and add one; there's no *standard* `splice` on non-array objects).

Comment: yea this is really confusing, I figured it was an obj because of: 'in/out into the obj object.'

Comment: You should describe context where this code is executed. I guess it's server code, then usually, each time a client do a request to your server, a new thread is launched. So if 10 clients send request in same time, you will have 10 instances of "obj" running in different threads.

Comment: What is *"the expected thing"*? If your expectation is that things will behave according to the well-defined behavior described in the spec, then the answer is *"yes"*.

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear enough. Here it goes then: obj is indeed an object and index can be an alphanumeric value. So, splice does not work in objects, instead should use delete. Same question then, is it ok to use delete inside a foreach of an object? It is server side code, node.js.

Comment: @Luciano: To correct the question, use the "edit" link on the question. (Two reasons: 1. First and foremost, so the question is correct, and 2. So people who've voted a while ago can change their votes; after a while, votes get "locked in" and can't be changed until/unless the question is changed.)

Comment: @Luciano: You're still not defining what is "expected" or what would make it "OK". You seem to have something bad that may happen when mutating a collection you're iterating, but you're not telling us what that is. There's no context. Are you talking about data races? Are you wondering if other code will see the effect of the splice or delete? If so, do you want them to see the effect?

Answer (score 2):

> obj is indeed an object and index can be an alphanumeric value. So, splice does not work in objects, instead should use delete. Same question then,is it ok to use delete inside a foreach of an object?

You're not doing `forEach` on `obj`. (You can't, `forEach` is only defined for array-like things.) You're doing `forEach` on an array created by finding all of the own enumerable properties of `obj` via `Object.keys`.

Let's look at the code with the change you describe above and the syntax error corrected:

```
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(key) { 
   if (key == 'sth')
      delete obj[key];
});
```

Sure, you can delete properties from `obj` within the `forEach` callback on the array from `Object.keys`. It has no effect at all on the array that you're looping over.

---

Side note: When you use `delete` on an object, on V8 (the JavaScript engine NodeJS uses) and some others it markedly reduces the performance of looking up properties of that object later, because it goes from the optimized version to a "dictionary mode" version. Of course, this only matters if you've identified the object as the source of a performance problem; until then, delete away... :-)

Comment: thank you! So, if `delete` reduces performances that much, what should be use instead of it?

Comment: @Luciano: It completely depends on what your code is doing. Sometimes setting the value `undefined` on the property is a good answer. Sometimes creating a new object that just has the properties you want to keep is a good answer. Sometimes being fine with the potential performance issue is a good answer.